# VBA checkbox.visible = true does not work

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-access-2010

I have a subform which is bound to a table called AdditionalTopics. The subform has 4 check boxes each of them is bound to the corresponding fields in the AdditionalTopics table. The subform is connected to the main form with the Program_ID field. Now if a Program_ID does not exist in the AdditionalSubTopics table then the subform goes blank. I wrote some vba code that makes the checkboxes on the subform visible when the recordset is empty. The recordset gets executes the following query:

```
select Program_ID from AdditionalSubTopics where Program_ID =  '" & progID & "';
```

and progID contains the value of the main forms programID field.
My code looks something like this:

```
If rsAddTopic.EOF = True Then
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkEducation.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkHealth.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkEnvSust.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkCommEconDev.Visible = True
End If
```

Here if the recordset is empty then the check boxes should be visible but its not working.

Can someone help Please
Thank you

@GordThompson. You are right. The checkboxes are bound to the AdditionalTopics table and the main form is connected to the Program table. Not all programs have a topic listed in the AdditionalTopics table. So, when I select the record on the main form that does not have a record in the AdditionalTopics table, the subform goes blank.  I guess that is how its supposed to work. But I do not want it to go  blank, instead the subform should show the checkboxes with non of them selected, allowing the users to select the boxes that would insert a new record in the AdditionalTopics table. To get this do I need to create subform that is not connected to the mainform and have the checkboxes not bounded to any table and write some vba code to update the tables or is there a better way to get this. Please help.

Comment: If the answer below does not work, please tell us where is this code, in Form_Open(), Form_Load(), Form_Current(), Form_Close(),... and how are you sure that rsAddTopic.EOF is true ? if not add a MsgBox inside the condition to check.

Comment: Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, but if the checkboxes are bound to fields in the Record Source of the subform and there are no records to display in the subform then it only seems logical (to me, at least) that the checkboxes would not be visible because there is no underlying record for them. In other words, setting `.Visible = False` can hide something that does exist, but setting `.Visible = True` cannot force the display of something that does *not* exist.

Comment: @Gord Thompson, you have seen just.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors?  This should work, so I am wondering if the visibility isn't getting updated on the form.

Try the following and let me know if it helps:

```
If rsAddTopic.EOF = True Then
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkEducation.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkHealth.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkEnvSust.Visible = True
 Me![Additional_Topic subform].Form!chkCommEconDev.Visible = True
 DoEvents
End If
```

There is a Form_Current event that occurs after the recordset on a form changes.  This may be a way to avoid the DoEvents(performance intensive or so they say).

Comment: With your updated question, since they are "bound" checkboxes, are we talkign they are not at all visible or just grayed out?  If grayed, have you looked at the CheckBox.TripleState property?  If you set it to false, they will display as unchecked and still allow you to update their values.  However, since this is a subform, it may now NEED a subform.form.recordsource set to a newly created row, if the row is null.

Comment: The checkboxes are not at all visible. Can I use the triple state property to make the checkboxes visible when the recordsource row is null?

Comment: I haven't tested it in that situation - did you have any luck?  In this case, it may be easier to add a "blank" row keyed to the master table before opening the subform.

Comment: triple state did not work, in that situation. I am working on your idea of using a blank row.